# Is the tag [crossbreed] necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [crossbreed](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossbreed) that only has two questions. I'm not really sure I see what the tag is adding to the questions, they seem to be a bit meta/descriptive to me.

Are these tags worth keeping around? What types of questions should be using the tag?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know. Looking at both questions currently tagged, they're asking about the effect of crossbreeding on a behaviour or health attribute and so the concept is specifically relevant to the question. I think the tag may be more useful as [crossbreeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossbreeding) instead, though, making it more appropriate as a stand-alone tag.

Comment: Would a tag for [crossbreeding] be an important enough distinction from the existing [breeding] tag?

Comment: @MattS. - Crossbreeding introduces other conditions beyond normal same-breed breeding in most species of animals, so I tend to think so. In the case of one question, for example, the crossbreeding implication was about a behavioural trait that would definitely not be eliminated by normal breeding.

Comment: I agree with the change to [tag:crossbreeding], especially because it removes the pluralization need for [tag:crossbreed].